# How to close the menu when clicking on the document (EventListener)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to add an **EventListener** to the document to close my menu, but it seems that none of the `event.stopPropagation()`; actually listen to me :/ can anyone give me a hand here? Please

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./header.css";

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            language : "en"
        }
    }

    openMenu = () => {
        let menuPaths = document.getElementById('menu');
        let hideAnimation = () => {
            menuPaths.classList.remove('animate-left');
            menuPaths.classList.add('animate-right');
        }
        let showAnimation = () => {
            menuPaths.classList.remove('animate-right');
            menuPaths.classList.add('animate-left');
        }
        menuPaths.classList.toggle('show');
        if(menuPaths.classList.contains('show')) {
            showAnimation();
        } else {
            hideAnimation();
        }
    } 

    render() {
        //user logged in? render nav. Else, render login/signup
        const userAction = (
            <div className='header_action'>
                <button className='header_action_signup orange-md-btn'>SIGN UP</button>
                <button className='header_action_login orange-md-btn'>LOGIN</button>
            </div>
        )

        return (
            <div className='header'>
                <div className="header_menu">
                    <img onClick={event => {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        return this.openMenu(event);
                    }} src={require("./pictures/hamburger_menu.svg")}/>
                </div>
                <div className='header_paths' id="menu">
                    <NavLink to='/index/acceuil'>Home</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to='/index/how'>How does it work</NavLink>
                    <a href= {BLOG_URL + '/'+ this.state.language +'/'}>Blog</a>
                    <a href={BLOG_URL + '/media/'}>Media</a>
                    <NavLink to='/index/contact'>Contact Us</NavLink>
                    <a href={PUBLIC_MARKETPLACE}>Marketplace</a>
                    <a href="#">Fr</a>
                </div>
                <NavLink to='/index/acceuil' className='header_logo' >
                    <img src={require("./pictures/logo_march2.png")}/>
                </NavLink>
                {userAction}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Header;
```

this is what I tried adding in the `openMenu` function

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            document.removeEventListener("click", this.hideAnimation());
})
```

I also tried attaching the removeEventHandler on click in the componentDidMount, that didn’t work and I've tried numerous combinations of `event.preventDefault();`. I got it before using jQuery, however now that I have to use react, I don't want to mix is with jQuery. Any ideas?

Comment: you have added the click to the document, which is fine, but not defined the target meaning you want to close if and only if your target matches - your target being anything other than the menu itself and that when it is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, you need to do toggling your menu with state but not changing the DOM directly.
2. From what I understand your question, you want to close the menu upon clicking outside of the menu. If it is so, you might wanna use [react-onclickoutside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickoutside) and create `handleClickOutside` function and passed it to the HOC.

Comment: hello @kyaw-siesein! Thank you for the reply! 
so for 1. something like this.state = {menuToggle : false} and then conditionally render the whole header paths based on the state?
2. Yup, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. It's a little strange that I can't do this relatively easily with react, and have to import an extra library :( I try to keep the modules to the minimum if I can

Comment: 1. Yes
2. Yes as well. There is nothing wrong with adding extra package to your add. Even though u might have a lot of packages, the size of some of the packages were pretty small. Changing DOM directly were never best practise. Instead you can create `refs` but refs are mostly for focus and stuff like that

Comment: Alright, thank you :) I changed to state toggle and ill install the npm package tonight and give it a whirl